# Node.js + setInterval = Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple Node.JS script (just a script, no server), which is supposed to do a thing every 24 hours. But after about 8 hours I see this in the error log:

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/user/dev/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:79:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:910:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Forever restarting script for 1 time
```

I'm sure this is stupid and it's an easy fix, but I just can't find it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your code it would be hard to say, for sure. However, the error suggests something to do with your MySQL connection: perhaps -- if you're keeping it open -- this is dropping out after a long period of inactivity.

Comment: It looks like the connection was closed from the other side. It would be helpful to see some code.

Comment: I'm making a few $.get requests and some MySQL queries. Code coming in a few minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're keeping an open connection to a remote MySQL server.  The remote server is closing the connection after 8 hours of idle connection.  So you have two options.  Either you send a keepalive request or you disconnect after your initial request and then open the connection again when timer initiates the next event.

## Keepalive

If you want to send a keepalive request, simply setup a `select 1` on an interval timer.

`select 1` is just a simple query that will cause MySQL to return a result of `1` and reset the MySQL server's connection timeout.  It would look something like this.

```
function keepalive() {
  connection.query('select 1', [], function(err, result) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    // Successul keepalive
  });
}
setInterval(keepalive, 1000*60*5);
```

## Pooling

However, you're better off using the mysql module's [pool functionality](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections).  It will connect to the MySQL server on an as-needed basis and will handle disconnects for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to test this without waiting for 8 hours? :)

Comment: You can set the MySQL server's timeout value lower.  Set the connection timeout value to 15 minutes and test.

Comment: Ok, I will accept your answer for now, it looks like I will have to wait to be sure.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov a `select 1` will return a 1.